# How to merge one ordered dict and one dict together?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries I want to merge using both keys and values. The first is an ordered dictionary, while the second is a regular one. Both dicts have the same length.

```
ord_dict = OrderedDict([(0, 369670), (1, 370622), (2, 267034), ...])
reg_dict = {0: (0, 0), 1: (0, 1), 2: (0, 2), ...}
```

The desired result is a new dict where the key is the tuple of `reg_dict` and the value is the second element of each tuple in `ord_dict`.

In this example, the result should look like this:

```
merged_dict = {(0, 0): 369679, (0, 1): 370622, (0, 2): 267034, ...}
```

How to do this?

Comment: "value is the second element of each tuple", you mean **value** associated with the key in the `OrderedDict'?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
merged_dict = {reg_dict[k]: v for k, v in ord_dict.items()}
```

This will result in

```
{(0, 0): 369670, (0, 1): 370622, (0, 2): 267034}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you retreive a value from an OrderedDict but if it was a normal dict you could do something like this:

```
merged_dict = dict([ (v, ord_dict.get(k)) for k, v in reg_dict.iteritems() ])
```